# Colab Standard CPU, GPU performance test error: TF 1 GPU vs CPU bad performance 1x

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, google-colaboratory

I have problems getting tensorflow 1.x GPU utilization to work in Colab Notebook
I run the test: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/gpu.ipynb#scrollTo=v3fE7KmKRDsH
And in Tf1 the CPU and GPU speed is the same.
Changing to Tf2 the speed is significantly better between CPU/GPU
Anything I need to do to make it work in TF1?

regards,
Magnus

Comment: This was an issue in `TF1.X` and it is fixed in `TF2.X`. It keeps better in new versions. Unfortunately tensorflow team are not accepting changes to `TF 1.X` unless they are security fix related issues. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. They should, 'cause we need to run TensorRT and we can't create models for TF2. It can not be migrated to TensorRT SSD.